# bison: a specific number of recursions?

Tags: parsing, recursion, bison, flex-lexer, bisonc++

I've been writing a parser with flex and bison for a few weeks now and have ground to a halt on account of a double recursion, the definitions of which are similar for the first few rules. Bison always chooses the wrong path at one particular stage and crashes because the grammar doesn't fit. The bison code looks a little like this:

```
set : 
TOKEN_    /* token */
QString
QString
Integer  /* number of descrs (see below) */
M_op     /*'M' optional*/
alts;
```

and

```
alts  :
alt | alts alt ;

alt   :
QString
pName_op   /* empty | TOKEN1 QString */
deVal_op    /* empty | TOKEN2 Integer */
descrs
;
```

and

```
descrs  :   
descr | descrs descr ;
descr :
QString
QString_op   /* optional qstring */
Integer
D_op         /* optional 'D' */
```

Bison stays in the `descrs` recursion and never exits it to progress to the next `alt`. The integer that is read in in the initial block, however, tells us how many instances of `descr` are going to come. So my question is this:

Is there a way of preparing bison for a specific number of instances of the recursion so that he can exit this recursion and enter the recursion "above"? I can access this integer in the C code, but I'm not aware of syntax for said move, something like a `descrs : {for (int i=0;i<n;++i){descr}}` (I'm aware that probably looks ridiculous)

Failing this, is there any other way around this problem?

Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is bison giving you shift/reduce errors when you build? We don't have enough material to go on yet.

Answer (score 1):

A context-free grammar cannot be contingent on semantic information. Yet, that is precisely what you are seeking: you wish the *value* of a numeric token to be taken into account in the *syntax* of an expression.

As a request, that's not unreasonable or immoral; it's simply outside of the reach of context-free grammars. And `bison` is intended to create parsers for context-free grammars. So it's simply not the correct tool for this problem.

Having said that, it is *possible* to use bison in this manner, if you are using a reasonably recent version of `bison` which includes support for GLR grammars. Bison`s GLR support includes the option of using semantic predicates to control the parse. (See the [bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantic-Predicates) for details.) A solution based on that mechanism is possible, and probably not *too* complicated.

Much easier -- if the grammar allows for it -- would be to use a top-down parser. Parsing a number and then that number of `descr`s would be trivial in a recursive-descent parser, for example.

The liberal use of `FOO_op` non-terminals in the grammar suggests that top-down parsing would not be problematic, but it is impossible to say for sure without seeing the entire grammar. Artificial non-terminals (like `FOO_op`) often cause shift-reduce conflicts in LR(1) languages, because they force an immediate shift/reduce decision to be made. In an LR(1) language, a production of the form: `A → ω B? χ` 
would normally be rendered as the pair of productions `A → ω B χ; A → ω χ`, rather than the substitution `Bop → B | ε; A → ω Bop χ`, in order to avoid creating conflicts with other productions of the form `C → ω ζ` where `FIRST(ζ) ∩ FIRST(B ∪ ω) ≠ ∅`.

Comment: thanks a lot for that rici, you lost me a bit towards the end, but i'll have a look at that manual and see if i can construct some sort of solution out of that. changing tools is no longer an option, i've been building this parser for weeks now (seems like years...)

Comment: @TomM: I was puzzled by the fact that a `set` has the numeric constant, and then any number of `alt`s, each of which has a fixed number of `descr`s. Is that correct? Anyway, you should be able to do this with a `glr-parser` and the semantic constraint, as indicated, but you'll need mid-rule actions in order to make the repetition count available to the `alt` and `descrs` rules. If that works, it will be because your grammar is (mostly) LL(1).

Comment: your understanding is correct. i have solved it without resolving to the `glr-parser`, i tried that but it kept telling me my syntax was ambiguous. i solved it just by taking the first `QString` out of ´alt´ and squeezing it between `M_op` and `alts` in the first block, then letting the internal code take care of it. possibly a lazy solution but it works a treat. thanks for the help though.

Comment: @TomM: That's cool, although I don't see how that can be the same language. However, I don't really know what language you're trying to parse and I'm glad you found something which works. With a glr-parser, you can treat ambiguous grammar warnings as warnings: a GLR parser will parse any context-free grammar, but (the bison implementation) requires that you provide rules to disambiguate; that's the point of the semantic predicates, for example. Since bison can't tell whether your predicates work, it will still warn you that the grammar is ambiguous.